# VB Application has exe.Manifest extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a VB application (`Sampleproduct`), when I run the application, in `Bin` directory I am seeing a file `Sampleproduct.exe.manifest` show up.

Could anyone tell me why I get that manifest file and why it has my exe extension?

I am expecting this application should have only exe file.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

An assembly manifest contains all the metadata needed to specify AssemblyName, AssemblyTitle, publicKey, and The manifest is stored as binary data.

The manifest can be viewed programmatically by making use of classes from the System.Reflection namespace.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, Can I use that exe.manifest file to run this application in other server?

Comment: I think the manifest is a metadata that wraps your currently app.exe you will need to have both files